# XQuery: how to sequentially find occurrence of expected data (similar to state machine)

Tags: xml, xquery, saxon

Good day, firstly thank you for reading my XQuery question.

I need to implement a function in XQuery to sequentially detect items in a data structure. As I am new to XQuery I am still finding some concepts unfamiliar and greatly appreciate help from those of you who have years of experience compared to my few weeks with XQUery/Saxon.

This is part of a log file analysis and I have already boiled down the relevant data into a more compact XML structure (see below) that is held in a sequence in my XQuery module. I now need to pass this sequence to a function that detects specific events within the data. My structure is as follows :-

```
<SEQUENCE><TIME>0.01</TIME><TAG>2100</TAG><FIELD>PRIMARY_MODE_CMD</FIELD><MODE>MODE1</MODE></SEQUENCE>
<SEQUENCE><TIME>0.57</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>PRIMARY_MODE_CNF</FIELD><MODE>MODE1</MODE></SEQUENCE>
<SEQUENCE><TIME>0.65</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>PRIMARY_MODE_CNF</FIELD><MODE>MODE1</MODE></SEQUENCE>
<SEQUENCE><TIME>1.29</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>PRIMARY_MODE_CNF</FIELD><MODE>MODE1</MODE></SEQUENCE>
<SEQUENCE><TIME>1.94</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>PRIMARY_MODE_CNF</FIELD><MODE>MODE1</MODE></SEQUENCE>
<SEQUENCE><TIME>2.57</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>PRIMARY_MODE_CNF</FIELD><MODE>MODE1</MODE></SEQUENCE>
<SEQUENCE><TIME>3.01</TIME><TAG>3800</TAG><FIELD>JAT_INITIALISE_CMD</FIELD><MODE>UPDATE_JAT_INITIALISE_PARAMS</MODE></SEQUENCE>
<SEQUENCE><TIME>3.03</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>PRIMARY_MODE_CNF</FIELD><MODE>MODE1</MODE></SEQUENCE>
<SEQUENCE><TIME>3.03</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>INVALID_CMD_CNF</FIELD><MODE>INVALID</MODE></SEQUENCE>
```

The XQuery function ( e.g. '*declare function local:analyse_case_1($seq as element()*) as xs:boolean*' ) must take the entire sequence of elements (above) as it parameter and return 'true' if it finds three events in strict sequence, namely:

```
'2100 + PRIMARY_MODE_CMD + MODE1' - followed by:
'2900 + PRIMARY_MODE_CNF + MODE1' - followed by:
'3800 + JAT_INITIALISE_CMD + UPDATE_JAT_INITIALISE_PARAMS' - followed by:
'2900 + INVALID_CMD_CNF + INVALID'
```

The function will return false if it finds this order is incorrect, missing items etc. As a second requirement it should also return false if the time between these items is longer than 0.60

Having looked at XQuery in some detail over the past day or so I reckon this would have been straight forward to achieve in a compiled language but for some reason I can not see an immediate way through using XQuery. I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction please?

With thanks.

Comment: "Strict sequence", does that mean there may be no elements in between?

Comment: Yes there are lots of additional messages in the log that can be ignored - the requirement is to look only for the messages highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the impression your requirement is to find messages that are in sequence but not necessarily adjacent. That can be achieved by a query of the form

```
exists(
  SEQUENCE[TAG='2100' and FIELD='PRIMARY_MODE_CMD' and MODE='MODE1']
  /following-sibling::SEQUENCE[TAG='2900' and FIELD='PRIMARY_MODE_CNF' and MODE='MODE1']
  /following-sibling::SEQUENCE[TAG='3800' and FIELD='JAT_INITIALISE_CMD' and MODE='UPDATE_JAT_INITIALISE_PARAMS']
  /following-sibling::SEQUENCE[TAG='2900' and FIELD='INVALID_CMD_CNF' and MODE='INVALID'])
```

The second part of the question,

```
it should also return false if the time between these items is longer than 0.60
```

isn't clearly specified. Do you mean the time beween the first and the last, or the time between any pair of events? You can basically handle this by binding variables to the selected elements:

```
let $x := SEQUENCE[...],
    $y := $x/following-sibling[...],
    $z := $y/following-sibling[...][TIME lt $x/TIME + 0.6]
return exists($z)
```

Comment: So am I correct in thinking if I used '/following-sibling::*[TAG='2900' and FIELD='PRIMARY_MODE_CNF' and MODE='MODE1']' after 'SEQUENCE[TAG='2100' and FIELD='PRIMARY_MODE_CMD' and MODE='MODE1']' would give me all the PRIMARY_MODE_CNF's following a PRIMARY_MODE_CMD ? Thanks!

Comment: No, it would only give you those that match the requested TAG and MODE.

Answer (score 0):

The `for $x at $pos in $seq` construct is your friend:

```
for $x at $pos in $seq
  where $x/TAG eq "2100"
    and $x/FIELD eq "PRIMARY_MODE_CMD"
    and (some $y in subsequence($seq, $pos, count($seq))
           satisfies ($y/TAG eq "2900" and $y/FIELD eq "PRIMARY_MODE_CNF"))
  return $x
```

This is not the complete query yet, but you should be able to start from here. In practice, I would turn this into several functions. Note that the `subsequence` call inside the loop means that this query takes O(*n*²) time in the worst case.

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick reply. Yes there are lots of additional messages in the log that can be ignored - the requirement is to look only for the messages highlighted. So using the method you have described as I can understand - the first half of the query feeds the position of the first "2100 PRIMARY_MODE_CMD" in sequence into the 'subsequence()' function. The search then continues last position ('$pos') until the next match is found? Would I need to add a further if after the 'return' if I want to return a true/false?

Comment: @mactwixs: use `exists` to get a boolean, as Michael Kay demonstrates in his answer.

Comment: The following-sibling solution assumes that the sequence shown is a sequence of siblings. I agree that on reflection, it's not 100% clear from the question that this is the case.